# How can I prevent a JXTreeTable root node from collapsing?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtreetable

To prevent a `JTree` node from collapsing, you can use the `setExpandedState()` method.

I dont see a similar method for the SwingX `JXTreeTable` class, and it seems that `JXTreeTable` doesnt extend `JXTree` (which extends JTree).

Any suggestions as to how I can prevent a root node from collapsing on a `JXTreeTable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may add *tree-will-expand* listener with `addTreeWillExpandListener()` to prevent a tree node from expanding or collapsing.

For example to prevent collapsing:

```
treeTable.addTreeWillExpandListener(new TreeWillExpandListener() {
    public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent e)
            throws ExpandVetoException {
    }

    public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent e)
            throws ExpandVetoException {
        throw new ExpandVetoException(e);
    }
});
```

See [How to Write a Tree-Will-Expand Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treewillexpandlistener.html) for some examples.

`JXTreeTable` also has a set of methods for collapsing and expanding tree nodes: 
`expandPath()`, `expandAll()`, `collapsePath()` and `collapseAll()`. Maybe these can be helpful.